# How to change App Name on Recent Task list? - Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-recents

Does anyone know how the Recent Tasks list in Android populates the name it displays next to each app?  I would like to change this from the name of the launcher activity to something else.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the name of your app altogether or ONLY what it displays in Recent Tasks?

Comment: Just what is next ot it on the Recent Apps list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
        setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(name));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading though the RecentsPanelView source code (ref 1), it seems like it just takes the package's label. That seems to be the only thing you can change.

ref 1: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/systemui/recent/RecentsPanelView.java#RecentsPanelView.TaskDescriptionAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29

Comment: That's a bummer. Maybe I should ask this as another question, but Can I change the text in the ActionBar to be something other than the Activities label?